# Sort nested ansible dictionary by key

Tags: python, ansible

We have an ansible task like this

```
- name: Migrate Zookeeper settings
  zoo_import:
    version: "{{ item[0] }}"
    content: "{{ item[1] }}"
  with_items: "{{ zk_import | dictsort }}"
```

The *zoo_import* module expects sting *version* and dict *content* and I guess *dictsort* produces list of tuples.

So how do I pass a list item to the module? The most obvious variant content: {{ dict(item[1]) }} ends with "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

Thanks.

PS If it is important, the zk_import dictionary before sorting is like

```
zk_import:
  v20200420:
    to_update:
      '/path1/key1/': 'value2'
      '/path2/key1/': 'other value'
    to_delete:
      '/path/key/': 'value2'
      '/path/key1/subkey': 'other value'
  v20200425:
      etc...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: the value you're providing to the `content` key of the `zoo_import` module *is* a dictionary. `dictsort` returns `(key, value)` tuples, so `item[0]` is the key, and `item[1]` is the value of that key, which is a dictionary, which seems to be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ansible >= 2.5, you should use `loop` instead of `with_items`:

```
loop: "{{ zk_import | dictsort }}"
```

In Ansible <= 2.4, you need to use:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ zk_import | dictsort }}"
```

It is a special behavior of `with_items` that is [documented](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops):

> Please note that `with_items` flattens the first depth of the list it is provided and can yield unexpected results if you pass a list which is composed of lists. You can work around this by wrapping your nested list inside a list:
>
> ```
> # This will run debug once with the three items
> - debug:
>     msg: "{{ item }}"   vars:
>     nested_list:
>       - - one
>         - two
>         - three   with_items:
>     - "{{ nested_list }}"
> ```